# Node-RED websocket connection failed with error invalid frame header

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, ibm-cloud, node-red

I have a very simple application node deployed on IBM Bluemix. This node app will programatically starts a node RED instance on the same machine and serve the node RED UI on /red endpoint.

There is an endpoint /startinstance which will start the node RED instance

This is the code I am using:

```
var RED = require('node-red');
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app);

var port = env.PORT:

var settings = {
    httpAdminRoot: '/red',
    httpNodeRoot: '/api',
    userDir: instance.userDirectory,
    functionGlobalContext: { }
};

app.get('/startinstance', function(req, res, next) {
    RED.init(server, settings);
    // Serve the editor UI from /red
    app.use(settings.httpAdminRoot,RED.httpAdmin);

    // Serve the http nodes UI from /api
    app.use(settings.httpNodeRoot, RED.httpNode);

    RED.start();
});

app.get('/stopinstance', function(req, res, next) {
    RED.stop();
});

server.listen(port);
```

I node RED UI is embedded as an `iFrame` in the main application UI.

This works fine and I can to start the node RED instance successfully. When I access the node RED UI for the first time, it works fine. But when I stop the instance and restart it, it throws an web socket error in google chrome console as shown below:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://myapp.mybluemix.net/red/comms' failed: Invalid frame header red.min.js:16

And this is error in Safari console:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://myapp.mybluemix.net/red/comms' failed: Compressed bit must be 0 if no negotiated deflate-frame extension

This setup is working fine for localhost and I am not sure why this is throwing error at Bluemix.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by stopping and starting the Node-RED instance? Also does the UI reconnect properly if you restart it? This is probably down to all the bluemix apps being proxied through the router

Comment: @hardillb Starting and stopping the instances is a requirement. Yes I tried to redeploy the app on some other bluemix account with different name but still the problem continues. I suspect it is because of the proxy but I am looking for references which can validate that it is this. I found a issue on [github](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1089) about this.

Comment: Have you tried using https/wss for the connection? In my experience, the bluemix network stack tends to leave WS connections alone if they are encrypted.

Comment: @knolleary I am not making this ws connection. node RED is making ws connections

Comment: If you access your node-red application using https, it will use a secure websocket connection under the covers.

Comment: @knolleary I am accessing the application using https only, but still the problem continues

Comment: From the browser error I see the host your are calling is myapp.mybluemix.net - have you masked the real host? Otherwise this is a default host and I think you should update with the right one